# How to get Ruby on Rails to generate a model using sql server 2008

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, rubygems

Ruby version: 3.0.2
Rails: 1.9.2
OS: windows 7
DB: sql server 2008 (r2)

I tried to execute the following command: rails generate model product

The error I get can be seen here: pastebin.ca/1965168

I tried to follow these two sites:
rubyrailsandwindows.blogspot.com/2008/03/rails-2-and-sql-server-2008-on-windows_24.html

www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/05/03/connecting-activerecord-to-sql-server.aspx

I ran the following: gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
which appeared to install the gem and i've confirmed that there is an activerecord directory in my ruby installation.

I also ran:gem install dbi-0.4.3

my database.yml file contains the following:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: sqlTest_development
  host: localhost
  username: sqlTest
  password: 
  pool: 20
  timeout: 50000

If you need any other information please let me know.  I've tried other sites but people just tell me I should switch to Linux which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just use active record?  Sorry not as familiar with SQL Server Connection..

```
:adapter => "sqlserver",
:host => ".\\SQLEXPRESS",
:database => "MyDB",
:username => "sa",
:password => "sa"
```

here's an example with odbc: http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/blob/master/test/connections/native_sqlserver_odbc/connection.rb

But I think this link to the actual gem will help the most:
http://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Platform-Installation---Windows

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say, that the guide from 2008 is to old...
( sqlserver adapter no longer needs dbi )
As Nick said: go to wiki of activerecord  adapter on Github